# wordpress: Display last record of Custom post type on home page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am a novice developer of WordPress.
I created a custom post type wp_locations to practice.

It has three numeric fields that are entered as `<input type="number">`: a phone_number; a fax_number and a zip_code 

`$wp_location_phone = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_phone',true);
 $wp_location_fax = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_fax',true);
 $wp_location_zipcode = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_zipcode',true);`

That works properly and stores the information.

I have a plugin to create the Custom Post Type and save a new record in WordPress.
Now I want to display this record on the home page in a table.

I searched but I could not run any suggestions. Please guide me with an example. Thanks

```
class wp_simple_location{

    private $wp_location_trading_hour_days = array();

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array($this,'set_location_trading_hour_days')); //sets the default trading hour days (used by the content type)
        add_action('init', array($this,'register_location_content_type')); 
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this,'add_location_meta_boxes'));
        add_action('save_post_wp_locations', array($this,'save_location')); //save location     
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this,'plugin_activate'));
        register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array($this,'plugin_deactivate')); 
    }

    //display function used for our custom location meta box*/
    public function location_meta_box_display($post){
        wp_nonce_field('wp_location_nonce', 'wp_location_nonce_field');

        //collect variables
        $wp_location_phone = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_phone',true);
        $wp_location_fax = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_fax',true);
        $wp_location_zipcode = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_location_zipcode',true);
/*
    // information is gathered here in a form. The relevant inputs are:
    <input type="number" name="wp_location_phone" id="wp_location_phone" value=" <?php echo $wp_location_phone;"?> />
    <input type="number" name="wp_location_fax" id="wp_location_fax" value=" <?php echo $wp_location_fax; ?>"/>
    <input type="number" name="wp_location_zipcode" id="wp_location_zipcode" value=" <?php echo $wp_location_zipcode;" ?> />
    */
    }

    //triggered when adding or editing a location
    public function save_location($post_id){
        // nonce & autosave checks removed from example as they are irrelevant

        //get our phone, email and address fields
        $wp_location_phone = isset($_POST['wp_location_phone']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['wp_location_phone']) : '';
        $wp_location_fax = isset($_POST['wp_location_fax']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['wp_location_fax']) : '';
        $wp_location_zipcode = isset($_POST['wp_location_zipcode']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['wp_location_zipcode']) : '';

        //update phone, email and address fields
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wp_location_phone', $wp_location_phone);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wp_location_fax', $wp_location_fax);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wp_location_zipcode', $wp_location_zipcode);

        //search for our trading hour data and update
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            //if we found our trading hour data, update it
            if(preg_match('/^wp_location_trading_hours_/', $key)){
                update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
            }
        }
        do_action('wp_location_admin_save',$post_id);
    }

} // end class
```

Other notes: 
The customer post type name is "wp_location" but the slug is "locations":

```
$args = array(
    [...]
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'locations', 'with_front' => 'true')
);
register_post_type('wp_locations', $args);
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what result you require. I don't understand what you mean by displaying the last saved post in a table on your homepage. What relevance has the table? Also, please note that questions on StackOverflow should include all the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Questions with clear, detailed and *relevant* information are more likely to get answers. Please also read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello<br/>
I added the code to the first post<br/>
I have a plugin<br/>
In this plugin when I save a new record in WordPress and the information is stored well<br/>
Now I want to display this record on the home page as a table
<br/>
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for adding the code and additional information. Now your question is more like what it should be, and we are in a position to be able to help! By the way, I edited your question to remove some of the extra code that wasn't needed, as unnecessary code just makes it more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search for "wp_simple_location" shows that you have taken this example from [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/real-world-example-wordpress-plugin-development/) and changed it.

Based on that, I'm going to amend the rest of that example to show you how to create a shortcode you can use.

**Assumptions:**

- I presume the code you posts isn't your from your test site, as it is
  not valid (e.g. you are missing many )
- I'm also going to assume that you only have 1 location - the
  sitepoint example allowed you add many but you appear to have removed
  that code

**Code:**

**1. Add back in the get_locations_output function.**

You deleted the get_locations_output function, which is how you actually display the information - which is what you want! So you need to add it back into your wp_simple_location class. I have changed it so it should work with your changes

// main function for displaying locations (used for our shortcodes and widgets)

```
public function get_locations_output(){
    //find locations
    $location_args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'wp_locations',
        'posts_per_page'=> 999,
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );

    //output
    $html = '';

    $locations = get_posts($location_args);
    //if we have a location it will be returned in an array, so loop through it
    if($locations){
        $html .= '<article class="location_list cf">';
        //foreach location
        foreach($locations as $location){
            $html .= '<section class="location">';
                //collect location data
                $wp_location_id = $location->ID;
                $wp_location_phone = get_post_meta($wp_location_id,'wp_location_phone',true);
                $wp_location_fax= get_post_meta($wp_location_id,'wp_location_fax',true);
                $wp_location_zipcode= get_post_meta($wp_location_id,'wp_location_zipcode',true);


                // output details only if any were entered
                if($wp_location_phone || $wp_location_fax || $wp_location_zipcode){
                    $html .= '<table>';
                    if(!empty($wp_location_phone)){
                        $html .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . $wp_location_phone . '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    if(!empty($wp_location_fax)){
                        $html .= '<tr><td>Fax: </td><td>' . $wp_location_fax. '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    if(!empty($wp_location_zipcode)){
                        $html .= '<tr><td>Zipcode: </td><td>' . $wp_location_zipcode. '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    $html .= '</table>';
                }

                //apply the filter after the main content, before it ends 
                //(lets third parties hook into the HTML output to output data)
                $html = apply_filters('wp_location_after_main_content', $html);

            $html .= '</section>';
        }
        $html .= '</article>';
    }    
    return $html;
} // end function
```

**2. Create a new class that adds a shortcode to let you include the information in pages **

Note: Proper practice is create the new new class in a separate php file and include it in your wp_simple_location class file, but to keep this example simple, add this to the bottom of the file containing your wp_simple_location class:

```
class wp_location_shortcode{

    //on initialize
    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array($this,'register_location_shortcodes')); //shortcodes
    }
    //location shortcode
    public function register_location_shortcodes(){
        add_shortcode('wp_locations', array($this,'location_shortcode_output'));
    }

    //shortcode display
    public function location_shortcode_output($atts, $content = '', $tag){

        //get the global wp_simple_locations class
        global $wp_simple_locations;

        //uses the main output function of the location class
        $html = $wp_simple_locations->get_locations_output();

        return $html;
    }
}

$wp_location_shortcode = new wp_location_shortcode;
```

**3. Use the shortcode to include the information **

To include the information in any page, you just need to use the following shortcode in the post editor:

`[wp_locations]`

**Note:**

You should also clean up your plugin code - for example the code starting *//search for our trading hour data and update* is not needed as you deleted the hours from the plugin. Also make sure all your php tags are correct!

As I mentioned, I have just changed the SitePoint example to work with your changes, so I haven't tested any of this. If you have any questions it might be a good idea to re-read the SitePoint tutorial because it explains the code in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your guide
Using the following code, the records in the locator are displayed on the home page
Please guide me to add two more things
1- On the home page, only display the last record
2- How to create a table like the following code
<table>
<tr>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Fax</th>
<th>ZipCode</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>wp_location_phone</td>
<td>wp_location_fax</td>
<td>wp_location_zip</td>
</tr>
</table> Thanks again

Comment: @FardadFarhang 1 - Use the shortcode in my answer. 2 - Just add the header row first  `$html .= '<table><tr> <th>Phone</th> <th>Fax</th> <th>ZipCode</th> </tr> <tr>';`and then a second row with just the values.

Comment: Thank you Dear FluffyKitten
Your help helped a lot.
But I have another question.
How to display only the last record?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "the last record". As per you assumptions, I thought there was only 1 record.

Comment: @FluffyHitten   Dear  Fluffy Hitten. Thanks for your very good guidance. 
I need to make changes to this plugin Ask this post, Or create a new post